# Use windows and asp concurrently

Tags: c#

Can we add a windows form in an asp web page.
Like if someone click on a button on web page(.aspx) user receive a windows form (.cs)
and then again switch to each other.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done.

The closest thing to do this would be to use Silverlight embedded in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no this cannot be done.

You can't embed a windows form application in a webpage.

[RIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Internet_application) (Rich Internet Applications) are what HTML 5 is about, and currently flash and silverlight are the closes things to what you are looking for.

As @Mitchel Sellers mentions, you can always link to an exe, save it and execute the downloaded file, but this is far from seamless.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not any way to do this.  Your only option would be for the user to click a link, download an .exe and then have the user launch the application.

The reason for this is that Windows Forms are designed to run on Windows, and run with a different permission set.  As such, a web application first of all could be running on a non-windows platform, and secondly, does not have the ability to actually launch an application on the users machine.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you did add some windows form UI (for eg a message box) to your asp.net application it will only be fired on your web server.. no client will ever get it on their side

I'm not exactly sure why would you need this? But the closest you can get to this is like "Mikael Svenson" said, Silverlight..